# Find through grep to file

Tags: bash, shell, grep, ksh

I am trying to send output from `find` to `file -b` command through `grep` ignoring specific files that I define in regex. As far as I know I think that you cannot pipe output into `file`.
Do you have any idea how can I do it without using any external files ?
I do not need to use grep for ignoring files, but I need to use specified regex to ignore files and output from utility `file`, so if there is another option I am open to it.

Thanks in advance :)

What have I tried:

```
find dir -type f -exec file -b {} \;
```

This works for me, but does not ignore any files

```
find dir -type f -exec grep -v 'file.' {} \; -exec file -b {} \;
```

Works as first example, but prints out the content of files, which I don't need

EDIT: I need to ignore file names and paths, not output from `file`

EDIT2: This is my folder

```
dir
dir/a
dir/a/b
dir/a/b/c
dir/a/b/c/file
dir/a/b/filec
dir/a/fileb
dir/filea
```

Every file is type of ASCII text, and my desired output is to use this regex `'file(a|b)'` to ignore files named `filea` and `fileb`, but not files named `file` and `filec` which does not fit in regex so the desired output from my commands would be

```
ASCII text
ASCII text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I underdstand right, something like:

```
find dir -type f -exec file {} + | grep -Ev ':\s*ASCII text|empty'
```

will list files which aren't `ASCII text` or `empty`.

If you need grep the filenames in advance:

```
find dir -type f -print | grep -v 'pattern' | file -b -f -
```

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I meant, I need to ignore name of files/path, not specific types of files @jm666

Comment: @HynekBernard just added the solution.

Comment: edited the question, I do not know how to use the grep in the 'middle' of commands to pipe it into file

Comment: when I finished writing my comment, your answer reloaded, now it works :) thanks

Comment: Enjoy, just note - the above will NOT work if the filenames containing `\n` (newline).

Answer (score 1):

With find

```
find dir -type f ! -name 'file[ab]' -exec file -b {} \;
```

Or perhaps just bash:

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in dir/**/file[^ab]; do
    file -b "$f"
done
```

Comment: Nice, though I suggest using `+` instead of `\;` in the `find` command so as to make do with (typically) a _single_ `file` invocation. Perhaps also worth mentioning that GNU and BSD `find` have nonstandard `-regex` / `-iregex` tests for true regex-based matching.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *ignore* a pattern you can use the `!` operator, it would work something like this:

```
find -type f ! -name "file[ab]"
```